# How to put file in HDFS using Airflow?

Tags: docker, hadoop, hdfs, airflow

I need to put the file in hdfs using the airflow dag task.
So, basically, I have installed docker and inside that, I have installed airflow, namenode, datanode, resourcemanager, etc.
So by doing ssh over namenode I'm able to put file in hdfs cluster.

But I want to put file in hdfs using airflow dag tasks, so that I can orchestrate everything in pipeline.

Anyone help me to put and get files from hdfs using airflow dag tasks.

Below is my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  postgres:                                           # create postgres container
    image: postgres:9.6
    container_name: postgres_container
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=airflow
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=airflow
      - POSTGRES_DB=airflow

  airflow:                                            # create airflow container
    build: './airflow_docker'
    container_name: airflow_container
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      - LOAD_EX=n
      - EXECUTOR=Local
    volumes:                                        # mount the following local folders
      - ./dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
      - ./data:/usr/local/airflow/data
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"                               # expose port
    command: webserver
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ -f /usr/local/airflow/airflow-webserver.pid ]"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 3
  namenode:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-namenode:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8
    container_name: namenode
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 9870:9870
      - 9000:9000
    volumes:
      - hadoop_namenode:/hadoop/dfs/name
    environment:
      - CLUSTER_NAME=test
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env

  datanode:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-datanode:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8
    container_name: datanode
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - hadoop_datanode:/hadoop/dfs/data
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9870"
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env
  
  resourcemanager:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-resourcemanager:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8
    container_name: resourcemanager
    restart: always
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9000 namenode:9870 datanode:9864"
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env

  nodemanager1:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-nodemanager:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8
    container_name: nodemanager
    restart: always
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9000 namenode:9870 datanode:9864 resourcemanager:8088"
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env
  
  historyserver:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-historyserver:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8
    container_name: historyserver
    restart: always
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9000 namenode:9870 datanode:9864 resourcemanager:8088"
    volumes:
      - hadoop_historyserver:/hadoop/yarn/timeline
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env
  
volumes:
  hadoop_namenode:
  hadoop_datanode:
  hadoop_historyserver:
```

And this is the hadoop.env file

```
CORE_CONF_fs_defaultFS=hdfs://namenode:9000
CORE_CONF_hadoop_http_staticuser_user=root
CORE_CONF_hadoop_proxyuser_hue_hosts=*
CORE_CONF_hadoop_proxyuser_hue_groups=*
CORE_CONF_io_compression_codecs=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec

HDFS_CONF_dfs_webhdfs_enabled=true
HDFS_CONF_dfs_permissions_enabled=false
HDFS_CONF_dfs_namenode_datanode_registration_ip___hostname___check=false

YARN_CONF_yarn_log___aggregation___enable=true
YARN_CONF_yarn_log_server_url=http://historyserver:8188/applicationhistory/logs/
YARN_CONF_yarn_resourcemanager_recovery_enabled=true
YARN_CONF_yarn_resourcemanager_store_class=org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.recovery.FileSystemRMStateStore
YARN_CONF_yarn_resourcemanager_scheduler_class=org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler
YARN_CONF_yarn_scheduler_capacity_root_default_maximum___allocation___mb=8192
YARN_CONF_yarn_scheduler_capacity_root_default_maximum___allocation___vcores=4
YARN_CONF_yarn_resourcemanager_fs_state___store_uri=/rmstate
YARN_CONF_yarn_resourcemanager_system___metrics___publisher_enabled=true
YARN_CONF_yarn_resourcemanager_hostname=resourcemanager
YARN_CONF_yarn_resourcemanager_address=resourcemanager:8032
YARN_CONF_yarn_resourcemanager_scheduler_address=resourcemanager:8030
YARN_CONF_yarn_resourcemanager_resource__tracker_address=resourcemanager:8031
YARN_CONF_yarn_timeline___service_enabled=true
YARN_CONF_yarn_timeline___service_generic___application___history_enabled=true
YARN_CONF_yarn_timeline___service_hostname=historyserver
YARN_CONF_mapreduce_map_output_compress=true
YARN_CONF_mapred_map_output_compress_codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec
YARN_CONF_yarn_nodemanager_resource_memory___mb=16384
YARN_CONF_yarn_nodemanager_resource_cpu___vcores=8
YARN_CONF_yarn_nodemanager_disk___health___checker_max___disk___utilization___per___disk___percentage=98.5
YARN_CONF_yarn_nodemanager_remote___app___log___dir=/app-logs
YARN_CONF_yarn_nodemanager_aux___services=mapreduce_shuffle

MAPRED_CONF_mapreduce_framework_name=yarn
MAPRED_CONF_mapred_child_java_opts=-Xmx4096m
MAPRED_CONF_mapreduce_map_memory_mb=4096
MAPRED_CONF_mapreduce_reduce_memory_mb=8192
MAPRED_CONF_mapreduce_map_java_opts=-Xmx3072m
MAPRED_CONF_mapreduce_reduce_java_opts=-Xmx6144m
MAPRED_CONF_yarn_app_mapreduce_am_env=HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/opt/hadoop-3.2.1/
MAPRED_CONF_mapreduce_map_env=HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/opt/hadoop-3.2.1/
MAPRED_CONF_mapreduce_reduce_env=HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/opt/hadoop-3.2.1/
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your HDFS commands/operations inside bash/shell script and call it in DAG using `BashOperator`. Before Put/Get HDFS file, if you want to check whether file exists then use Airflow HDFS operators like `HdfsSensor`, `HdfsFolderSensor` , `HdfsRegexSensor`. Please note that Airflow is workflow management/data pipeline orchestration tool, and it is not a data ingestion/ETL tool.

```
hdfs_operations_task = BashOperator(
    start_date=datetime(2020, 9, 9, 10, 0, 0, 0),
    task_id='hdfs_operations_task',
    bash_command="/hdfs_operations.sh " ,
    dag = dag)
```